# Install guest additions with Dockerfile

Tags: virtualbox, docker, guest-additions

Right now I'm using docker to build a personalized virtual environment for tensor flow development.

I will install fluxbox and guest additions ontop of an existing tensor flow Ubuntu Docker...

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential module-assistant
RUN m-a prepare
RUN m-a update
RUN sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

RUN apt-get -y install xorg openbox
RUN apt-get -y install fluxbox
RUN apt-get -y install gedit

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
```

Unfortunately `RUN m-a prepare exits with code 101` expecting me to Click on Install Guest Additions… from the VirtualBox Devices menu.

I am thinking that this is the same type of issue you get if you try to `apt-get install` without the `-y` option, the docker file results in a indeterminate state requiring user input and the whole thing crashes.

Now I have been looking for a couple hours now and I can't figure how to install guest additions in with my Dockerfile...

Any input would be awesome!

I also posted this question here : https://superuser.com/questions/1067118/install-guest-additions-in-dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You can install `virtualbox-guest-dkms` package instead, it contains the same guest drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```